# refresh shows different logo, sometimes a different background, what's the problem? sftp?

Tags: sftp

I'm trying to upload files to my client's Wordpress theme but the strangest things are happening. 1) When I update the css (a simple background-color change), upload, and hit refresh, the change doesn't show. 2) When I hit refresh on the site multiple times, sometimes a bigger sized logo shows and sometimes the background comes up tiled, and sometimes the background comes up not tiled. I'm transferring files through sftp (first time doing this). Could that be the issue? How can I resolve this? I tried clearing the cache but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Could be from several reasons

- there is a load balancer ( and the picture gets on one of the servers but not on the other )
- there is a cache problem ( try deleting the cached files from the browser )
- there is a wp cache plugin affecting this